# Передача функции в параметры другой функции

Tags: c++

```
void pr1(int a)
{
    std::cout<<"A: " << a;
}

void pr2(int a, int b)
{
    std::cout<<"A: " << a << "B: " << b;
}

void pr3(std::string s)
{
    std::cout<<s;
}

void print(/*Указатель на функцию и ее параметры*/)
{
    
}
```

Как можно в `print` передать для вызова какую-либо функцию? А так же все параметры, которая принимает сама функция. Как это можно сделать в стиле C, без использования, например, `std::function`

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  
    print(/*Параметры и указатель на функцию*/);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Разнотипные? Через шаблоны...

Comment: @Harry Я видел использование разных типов в качестве параметров без шаблонов, просто указывали в параметры самой функции ссылку на другую функцию, а потом через запятую параметры к ней, но реализации там не было, к сожалению

Comment: Возможно, вы имеете в виду [функции с переменным числом аргументов](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic). Но лучше все же шаблоны использовать

Comment: @Mister_Jesus Да, это. Но как передать теперь функцию `simple_printf ` в качестве параметра для другой функци?

Comment: Сделать специальный тип `using func = void(*)(int);`, допустим. А если принимать разные сигнатуры, то только шаблоны

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю точно, что именно требуется от вашей функции `print()`, по-этому привожу два варианта:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

//Вариант 1
template <typename TRet, typename... TArgs>
TRet print1(TRet (*pFunc)(TArgs...), TArgs... args)
{
    return pFunc(args...);
}

//Вариант 2
template <typename TRet, typename... TArgs>
TRet print2(TRet (*pFunc)(TArgs...), const char* pcszFmt, TArgs... args)
{
    printf(pcszFmt, args...);
    return pFunc(args...);
}

//собственно функция, указатель которой передаём в print()
void pr2(int a, int b)
{
    std::cout<<"A: " << a << ", B: " << b << std::endl;
} 


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Variant 1:" << std::endl;
    print1(pr2, 12, 7);
    std::cout << "-------------------------" << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Variant 2:" << std::endl;
    print2(pr2, "Arguments: a==%d, b==%d ---> function output: ", 12, 7);
    std::cout << "-------------------------" << std::endl << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Будет выведено:

```
Variant 1:
A: 12, B: 7
-------------------------

Variant 2:
Arguments: a==12, b==7 ---> function output: A: 12, B: 7
-------------------------
```

P.S. Замечу, что в функцию `print2()` следует передавать простые типы, такие как `int`, `char*` и пр. Например, `std::string` тут не покатит, т.к. `printf()` такое не понимает.